# Web form to excel sheet on network

Tags: html, windows, excel

Is there a way to use a web form (say a name and address textfields) on a local browser on a windows machine with no internet access to update an excel spreadsheet on the network?

IE Can I execute a BAT file on a local PC with GET parameters or something?

Comment: Do you have a web server somewhere on the LAN?

Comment: no it's a networked PC on a domain but IIS cannot be enabled

Comment: Then you need look elsewhere (such as C# or Java). This cannot be done using HTML or similar.